# Dynamic image resize system

Tags: php, image, imagick

I need a image resize system for a project so I decided to upload original images into DB encoded with with base64, I would like to keep stored only original images since they are easy to manage(add/edit/delete).

The output is made dynamically with php and IMagick atm.

The main problem I met is the output slow time, specifically the processing time needed it too long because I use resize+compress.

I need this compression because my visitors have slow internet connection and sometimes images are really big for just a preview.

Alternative solutions I though is to store in DB some resized images but won't be eficient because it will take more space and images size will change over time.

So, my question is: is there a method to deliver images dynamically faster? How?

Comment: why you storing your images in DB , its not an good practice

Comment: why not? could you please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get around caching the resized images in some way. The thumbnails don't need to be stored in the data base; you could also write them to disk. Only recompute the resized versions if the original image has changed.